# Is there a name for this technique involving breaking a term into multiple terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, factoring

I recently saw a solution to the quadratic equation $x^2-5x-6=0$ that involved re-writing the middle term, $-5x$, into two terms, $x-6x$, so that the expression could be factored and $x$ solved for, vis-a-vie:

$$x^2+x-6x-6=0\\x(x+1)-6(x+1)=0\\(x+1)(x-6)=0\\x=-1\quad\text{or}\quad x=6$$

Is there a name for this technique, like how “completing the square” names another technique?

Comment: I believe this is not a general technique for solving such problems, it is merely a way of demonstrating a known answer.

Comment: It's essentially a version of "factoring by [clever] grouping", although textbook examples of this technique tend to keep individual terms intact. An appropriate name here might be "factoring by [clever] *re*-grouping".

Comment: Wikipedia calls this [by inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Factoring_by_inspection).

Comment: Think I've seen it called "split" or "distribute" as in "*take $x^2+x-2$ and split/distribute the constant term between the other two $= (x^2-1)+(x-1)$*" but I don't have a reference handy, and I wouldn't consider it standard language, anyway.

Comment: The first step is called splitting the linear term; the second step is called factoring by grouping.  As Selrach Dunbar's answer states, the whole procedure is called the a-c method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technique is commonly referred to as "the a-c method".  I did a quick Google search for examples and came across [this](https://virtualnerd.com/algebra-2/quadratics/solve-equations-by-factoring/factoring-strategies/factor-by-a-c-method).

Bottom line:  *If a quadratic can be factored into two linear factors with **integer** coefficients* then the A-C Method will always produce those linear factors.

The first step is *not* just by inspection.  Rather, when using this procedure one multiplies $a\cdot c$ (the coefficient of $x^2$ by the constant) then brainstorms to find factors of this product that sum to $b$ (the coefficient of $x$).

Here $a \cdot c = 1 \cdot (-6) = -6$.  This product has factors of $1$ and $-6$ which sum to $b = -5$.  So one "breaks" $-5x$ into $1x + (-6)x$ and then continues as you have indicated.

Can you see how this procedure would work to factor $x^2+x-6$ into the product of two linear factors?

Answer (score 1):

@peterwhy and @blue

Thanks, both of you.

I’ve synthesised your replies into “factoring by clever inspection”

Comment: I once had a teacher who used to say “by intense observation “

Comment: "By prolonged observation" in the words of my differential equations prof. Although that term could refer specifically to a family of related techniques in the differential equations.